# JSON not deserialising into custom class

Tags: vb.net, json.net

This is my first experience with JSON. I've serialised a custom class into a List but it won't deserialise. Any help appreciated

```
Dim Appointments As New List(Of UserAppointments)()
Using dt As DataTable = GetUserAppointments(ApptRequest.UserID, ApptRequest.PeriodFrom, ApptRequest.PeriodUntil)
For Each appt As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Appointments.Add(New UserAppointments With {.AppointmentID = CType(appt.Item("UniqueID").ToString, Long)})
    Next
End Using
Dim JSON As String = js.Serialize(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Appointments))
```

which produces

> "[{\"AppointmentID\":33},{\"AppointmentID\":34},{\"AppointmentID\":35},{\"AppointmentID\":36},{\"AppointmentID\":37},{\"AppointmentID\":38},{\"AppointmentID\":39},{\"AppointmentID\":40},{\"AppointmentID\":373},{\"AppointmentID\":374},{\"AppointmentID\":375},{\"AppointmentID\":376},{\"AppointmentID\":377},{\"AppointmentID\":687}]"

When I try and deserialise it back again

```
Dim rslt As List(Of UserAppointments) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of UserAppointments))(JSON)
```

I get the following error

> Error converting value “[{“AppointmentID”:33},{“AppointmentID”:34},{“AppointmentID”:35},{“AppointmentID”:36},{“AppointmentID”:37},{“AppointmentID”:38},{“AppointmentID”:39},{“AppointmentID”:40},{“AppointmentID”:373},{“AppointmentID”:374},{“AppointmentID”:375},{“AppointmentID”:376},{“AppointmentID”:377},{“AppointmentID”:687}]” to type ‘System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NetworkRequests+UserAppointments]‘. Path ‘’, line 1, position 331.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is with this line. You are serializing it twice.

> Dim JSON As String =
>   js.Serialize(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Appointments))

Have you tried just

> Dim JSON As String =
>   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Appointments)

or is there a reason for doubling it up?

Comment: Thanks Ryan! that was exactly it :)

No reason, Simple Error, I copied it from another function that was not returning an object and I missed it. 4hrs of frustration, always the way!


Thanks again :)